# Should I refrain from using a loop in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a stored procedure that would process data on those table.

In order for me to processed those data I have to do a `while` loop, because I have to compute for the end date which is not present on on one table.

The end date of the first record should be the start date of the second record -1 day.

Now when I present this to my senior he told me that it's a big NO to use a loop inside a stored procedure. And the provided solution that my senior did is created a **view** using that table and created multiple union on it to generate the missing data that I needed.

Is my loop approach wrong? Should I refrain from using loop in my stored procedure in the future?

Comment: SQL is declarative; stored procedures are procedural.  I'd do everything I could to see if I could fulfill the requirement declaratively before I'd resort to a stored procedure.  No loops.

Comment: A loop is more often then not a bad choice. Try to do it without one. The "row-by-row" processing you do in a loop is also known as "slow-by-slow"

Comment: Instead of using loop, you could use windowed expressions (`over ... partition`) or use complex joins. Loops in 90-something percent cases aren't good practise in SQL.

Comment: Loops are iterative and cannot be as optimized as the set-based approaches. Using the `numbers` table is a neat alternative, read more here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to use a set based approach when working with problems which may require looping.

Almost always your while/for loops can be swapped with Conditional JOINs to make it set based. If it's a counter that you need, try using a tally table.

Example of a loop converted to Set problem using JOIN is like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.StartDate, B.EndDate
FROM
A LEFT JOIN B
ON DATEDIFF(d,A.EndDate,B.StartDate)=1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is *almost* always better to avoid any sort of `while` or `cursor`. In the situation you described, I believe you could avoid both a `while` loop or multiple `union` queries by leveraging the [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) window function.

Example using a [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) with a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select t.*
    , NextStartDate = lead(StartDate) over (
        partition by ForEachOfThisColumn -- e.g. AccountId, AssignmentId
        order by StartDate asc
      )
  from t
)
select cte.*
  , EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, NextStartDate)
from cte;
```

Example using a [**`lead()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) in a derived table / inline view:

```
select cte.*
  , EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, NextStartDate)
from (
  select t.*
    , NextStartDate = lead(StartDate) over (
        partition by ForEachOfThisColumn -- e.g. AccountId, AssignmentId
        order by StartDate asc
      )
  from t
  ) as cte;
```